# How to make a jQueryMobile scrollview with image lazy load?

Tags: jquery-mobile, lazy-loading

I have used jQueryMobile to build a *scrollview* which contains a list of images.
I want to add lazy loading for the images, but I can only load some images in the first part of the scroll. When I scroll to the later part, the images does not load.

http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/scrollview-direction.html -*Not working*

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: It looks like scrollview was removed from jQuery Mobile tests.  Could you find the scrollview you're referring to again?